# How to fill a discontinuous line

Tags: python, opencv, scipy, contrast

I am currently working on a vein finder device as a personal project. I have been able to process the images of the veins until this point ([attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqDYf.png)) using median filter, gaussian filter, otsu's binarization... I was wondering if there is any way of filling the gaps of the line so that the veins are even more visible. I  am using OpenCV and scipy.

I think that a dilate/erode approach would not be the best, since the vein has to be of the same exact width. The device aims to find the veins which are invisible to the human eye, if the nurse injects it a little bit to the right or left they would not inject it in the vein. I have updated the post with the code that I am using and the results ([step by step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVlb5.png)). I am trying to represent the vascularization as best as possible. I have painted in paint the image so you can get an idea of what I am looking for [painted image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omypO.png)

```
#LOAD IMAGE
img = cv2.imread('images/cropped.jpg')

#APPLY CLAHE
lab_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
l, a, b = cv2.split(lab_img)
clahe1 = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=25.0, tileGridSize=(8, 8))
clahe1_img = clahe1.apply(l)
updated_lab_img21 = cv2.merge((clahe1_img, a, b))
lab_img = cv2.cvtColor(updated_lab_img21, cv2.COLOR_LAB2BGR)
lab_img = cv2.cvtColor(updated_lab_img21, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#MEDIAN FILTER
median = cv2.medianBlur(lab_img, 3)
#GAUSSIAN FILTER
gblur = cv2.GaussianBlur(median, (3, 3), 0.5)

#WEINER FILTER (DEBLURRING)
filtered_img = wiener(gblur, (1, 1))

#OTSU BINARIZATION
filtered_img=filtered_img.astype("uint8")
ret2,otsu = cv2.threshold(filtered_img,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

#MEDIAN FILTER SECOND TIME
median2 = cv2.medianBlur(otsu, 5)

titles = ['Original','CLAHE','Gaussian', 'Median','Wiener','OTSU','Final image']
images = [img,lab_img,gblur, median,filtered_img, otsu, median2]

for i in range(7):
    plt.subplot(2, 4, i+1), plt.imshow(images[i], 'gray')
    plt.title(titles[i])
    plt.xticks([]),plt.yticks([])

plt.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, can you share the piece of code you are currently working so we can help you better? Also, opencv has some docs around dilate and erode which might help you. See [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/df6/tutorial_erosion_dilatation.html)

Comment: can you post the original picture as well?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve, however, some morphology (perhaps a Closing) might help. Without more details, it is hard to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

I can't solve your specific question, but I can propose a method for getting rid of little specs without affecting the edges of the channels.

If you use findContours and mask out the little bits, it'll clean up isolated regions in the image.

Before despeckling

[image]

After despeckling black specks

[image]

After despeckling white specks

[image]

```py
import cv2

# cut out small contours
def despeckle(mask, cutoff):
    # find contours
    _, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    # cut out small stuff
    cleaned = mask.copy();
    small_contours = [];
    for contour in contours:
        area = cv2.contourArea(contour);
        if area < cutoff:
            small_contours.append(contour);
    cv2.drawContours(cleaned, small_contours, -1, (0), -1);
    return cleaned;

# load image
img = cv2.imread("orig.png");
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

# improve contrast
clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=25.0, tileGridSize=(8, 8));
contrast = clahe.apply(gray);

# threshold
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(contrast,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY,101,2);

# median
mask = cv2.medianBlur(thresh, 3);
inverted = cv2.bitwise_not(mask);

# despeckle black
mask = cv2.bitwise_not(despeckle(inverted, 500));

# despeckle white
mask = despeckle(mask, 500);

# show
cv2.imshow("image", img);
cv2.imshow("mask", mask);
cv2.waitKey(0);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I did not know about the dilate, erode functions. What happens is that the line should be the exact same width (it is a device so nurses can find the veins to inject a needle, if they go a little bit to the right or left they would not inject it properly) so this may not be the approach that I am looking for. But thank you for collaborating!

Comment: Can you post the original image (color)?

Comment: Thank you Ian! That helped a lot. The image I accquire is always in BW because I am using infrarred (NIR). Do you think aqcuiring the images in BGR would help (It would be a pinkish color)? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Color could help. The blue veins against the skin might give better contrast compared to grayscale.